# Table td don't has same row width althought already making the css?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I think i still has some problem understanding html5 table. So my problem is very simple, i has many table and making it inline block.

```css
table.cihuy {
    padding: 6px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-collapse: collapse;
 width:300px;
 table-layout:fixed;
}

table.cihuy td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 4px;
 height: 45px;
 font-size:12px;
 vertical-align:top; 
}

td.left {
  width:70%;
}
```

```html
<table id="cetak0" class="cihuy"><tr><td>Komputer</td><td class="left">Poles-0100</td></tr><tr><td>MAC</td><td class="left"></td></tr><tr><td>Processor</td><td class="left"></td></tr><tr><td>Mainboard</td><td class="left"></td></tr><tr><td>VGA</td><td class="left"></td></tr><tr><td>Memory</td><td class="left"></td></tr><tr><td>Hardisk</td><td class="left"></td></tr><tr><td>Key/Mouse</td><td class="left"></td></tr></table>

<table id="cetak1" class="cihuy"><tr><td>Komputer</td><td class="left">RND-2D-01</td></tr><tr><td>MAC</td><td class="left"></td></tr><tr><td>Processor</td><td class="left">Intel Premium E5800 @ 3.20Ghz</td></tr><tr><td>Mainboard</td><td class="left">ASUSTeK P5KPL-AM SE (Socket 775)</td></tr><tr><td>VGA</td><td class="left">Intel G33/G31 Express Chipset Family</td></tr><tr><td>Memory</td><td class="left">DDR2 1024 Mbytes</td></tr><tr><td>Hardisk</td><td class="left">1 TB</td></tr><tr><td>Key/Mouse</td><td class="left">Logitech</td></tr></table>
```

I already making css .left and making the width 70% of table, meanwhile the table css is styled with width 300px. What i confused is... all the td has the same lenght, you can see the first table more short than the second one. Is there anything i miss ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-column-gap: 30px;
}

table.cihuy {
  padding: 6px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width:300px;
  table-layout:fixed;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

table.cihuy td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 4px;
  height: 45px;
  font-size:12px;
  vertical-align:top; 
}

td.left {
  width:70%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:600px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <table id="cetak0" class="cihuy"><tr><td>Komputer</td><td class="left">Poles-0100</td></tr><tr><td>MAC</td><td class="left"></td></tr><tr><td>Processor</td><td class="left"></td></tr><tr><td>Mainboard</td><td class="left"></td></tr><tr><td>VGA</td><td class="left"></td></tr><tr><td>Memory</td><td class="left"></td></tr><tr><td>Hardisk</td><td class="left"></td></tr><tr><td>Key/Mouse</td><td class="left"></td></tr></table>
    <table id="cetak1" class="cihuy"><tr><td>Komputer</td><td class="left">RND-2D-01</td></tr><tr><td>MAC</td><td class="left"></td></tr><tr><td>Processor</td><td class="left">Intel Premium E5800 @ 3.20Ghz</td></tr><tr><td>Mainboard</td><td class="left">ASUSTeK P5KPL-AM SE (Socket 775)</td></tr><tr><td>VGA</td><td class="left">Intel G33/G31 Express Chipset Family</td></tr><tr><td>Memory</td><td class="left">DDR2 1024 Mbytes</td></tr><tr><td>Hardisk</td><td class="left">1 TB</td></tr><tr><td>Key/Mouse</td><td class="left">Logitech</td></tr></table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Try this out! Hope it'll help

Comment: it's there any solution to make the table inline?

Comment: Check now, I have updated and make the tables inline

Answer (score 0):

The content in you column (`Poles-0100`) is not long enough to force the table to expand further than it needs to go. If you add a longer string it will expand out to 70%.

Try without `display:inline-block;`